# How do I store and send cookie headers in an Android app?

Tags: php, android, cookies

I have an Android app that checks a URL which I control. However, I can't seem to set/pull the cookies onto/from the device. This works great on my desktop but not the phone itself.

The server-side code is

```
<?php 

if(!$_COOKIE['test']) {
$newid=rand(1000,9999999);
echo base64_encode("$newid"); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` SET `id`='".$newid."', `channel`='0', `activation_date`=now(), `last_view`=now()");
setcookie('test', $newid, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 3015)); 
} else {

echo base64_encode($_COOKIE['test']); 

}

?>
```

Comment: [`uniqid()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: Also, Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Ok - still don't know how to store cookies into the android app/device when it hits/poll/parse the url I have on a remote webserver?